# Windows Forms, Element Host and style inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, styles, elementhost

I have a Windows Forms application in which I host a usercontrol created with WPF. This is done using the Element Host class. All WPF elements in the element host container inherit the windows forms style, including fonts, etc.

I want to prevent that from happening. All elements should inherit the default WPF style, so the fonts (and other styles) are the same. How can I achieve that?

I do not want to set all defaults myself.

[image: Example Window]
[Example Window](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40912731/test.png), note the difference between the 'g' in 'segeo' and 'S' in 'MS Sans Serif'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

Just add:

```
this.InheritanceBehavior = InheritanceBehavior.SkipToAppNext;
```

to your constructor of your UserControl.